# l[20]ve: invalid chunk type?

Tags: iphone, nsurlconnection, mkmapview

I don't know why I'm getting this error. I'm also getting an EXC_BAD_ACCESS issue from the following code. Any ideas why?

Running breakpoints on the `didRecieveResponse` and `didRecieveData` and `didFinishLoading` shows the first two get run and mid way through recieving data the program crashes.

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
    // starts... :)
    plistContentsData = [NSMutableData data]; //NSMutableData - inst in head

}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    [plistContentsData appendData:data];
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
    mellowListings = [[NSArray alloc] initWithData:plistContentsData]; //NSArray - inst in head

    NSLog(@"%@",mellowListings);

    CLLocationCoordinate2D newLocation;

    int counter = 0;

    for(NSDictionary *tempDict in mellowListings){
        NSLog(@"%f",([[tempDict objectForKey:@"lat"] floatValue]));
        NSLog(@"%f",([[tempDict objectForKey:@"long"] floatValue]));
        newLocation.latitude = ([[tempDict objectForKey:@"lat"] floatValue]);
        newLocation.longitude = ([[tempDict objectForKey:@"long"] floatValue]);
        TCPlaceMarker *placemark = [[TCPlaceMarker alloc] initWithCoordinate:newLocation];
        placemark.title = [tempDict objectForKey:@"name"];
        placemark.subtitle = [tempDict objectForKey:@"address1"];
        placemark.source = [[tempDict objectForKey:@"source"] lowercaseString];
        placemark.tag = counter;
        [mapView addAnnotation:placemark];
        counter++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
plistContentsData = [NSMutableData data];
```

You create an autoreleased NSMutableData object and it may become invalid right after you exit didReceiveResponse method. You need to retain `plistContentsData` to fix that error.

Comment: ah, that works. :) Thanks, erm, still getting the `invalid chunk type` error though. :( any ideas there?

Comment: I have no idea - with breakpoints in the error doesn't occur. :/

Comment: but is this an error (and app crashes) or just a console message? Never seen it myself and googling does not give anything relevant it seems...

Comment: oh i see... the app doesn't crash. and yeah, I spent hours crawling google and not finding anything. :/ its just in the console, but I don't know what it means. I guess if everything still works its fine?

Comment: Yes, if it works you can live with it :) May be it is worth asking on official apple forums? If you find an answer let us know please